# Stack text sorting issue

Tags: flutter, sorting, stack

```
hild: Stack(
                        // Stack 위젯 추가
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            // 첫 번째 Column
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '11',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '30',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            // Positioned 위젯 추가
                            top: 50, left: 10, // 원하는 위치로 조정
                            child: Text(
                              '|',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.red,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            // 두 번째 Column
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 80), // 필요한 공간 제공

                              Text(
                                '12',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '20',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Design good',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        fontSize: 40,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Job',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        fontSize: 50,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 0,
                            left: 40,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text('AppBar'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

If you use the positioned bottom instead of the bottom of the container to rise, and use the left, I don't see why it rises and goes to the right. All sort widgets give the same result, but I don't know why.

I wanted to put the app bar in the middle of the bottom. But I don't know why, because even if I use all the alignments, it doesn't work my way and it moves weirdly.